# How to hide the right sidebar at start in Trello

Tags: trello

I would like to hide the right sidebar at the start. Especially hide the activities for normal user.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The right sidebar can be hidden by clicking the button on its upper left, circled below:

[image: sidebar]

Trello remembers this choice: the sidebar will remain hidden. If you want to show it again, click Show Menu on the right:

[image: show]